# Compiler warning C4383 for native pointer dereferencing

Tags: c++-cli

I use operator* to deference a pointer inside my C++/CLI class and the compiler gives a warning about this operation:

```
C4383: 'instance_dereference_operator' : the meaning of dereferencing a handle can change, when a user-defined 'operator' operator exists; write the operator as a static function to be explicit about the operand
```

How can I avoid this warning? This is the code:

```
ref struct MyClass
{
    // ...
    T& operator*()
    {
        return *m_pValue;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Native C++ supports both instance and static operator overloads.  Managed code however only supports the latter.  If your code is meant to be usable by other managed languages then you need to heed the warning and write a static overload instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented as static operator overload as @hans-passant suggests:

```
static T& operator*(MyClass %obj)
{
    return *obj.GetActualValue();
}
```